# How to show an Indicator with key On/Off (Pine Script)

Tags: plot, input, pine-script

```
//code

//@version=4
study("Enable test indicator ")

// in setup panel, I can enable or disable with instruction below

habilitaRSI = input(true, "Enable", type = input.bool, group = "RSI", inline = "RSI Period")

rsiLength = input (14, "RSI Comprimento", type = input.integer, group="RSI", inline = "RSI Period")
rsiVal = rsi(close, rsiLength)

// below I need Plot with display.all ou display.none  - depends on (if check is enable or not in setup panel)

if habilitaRSI
plot(rsi(close,14),display=display.all)
else
plot(rsi(close,14),display=display.none)
```

but I got this error on "IF"  command

> Error: Processando script... line 18: Cannot use 'plot' in local
> scope.;

So, how can I Plot using "IF" ?

I need Plot many indicators in only one script and use" check enable" or "check disable"  in setup panel

To do this I am using a parameter(option) in Plot command that are (display.all and/or display.none)

like:  `plot(rsi(close,14),display=display.none)`

It's depends on (if check is enable or not in setup panel)

Answer (score 1):

The **plot()** function should be called in the global scope only and could not be executed from the local block. Use the ternary **?:** operator directly in the **series=** argument of the **plot()** function, a simplified version:

```
//@version=4 
study("Enable test indicator", overlay = false)
habilitaRSI = input(true, "Enable", type = input.bool, group = "RSI", inline = "RSI Period")
rsiLength = input (14, "RSI Comprimento", type = input.integer, group="RSI", inline = "RSI Period") 
rsiVal = rsi(close, rsiLength)
plot(habilitaRSI ? rsiVal : na)
```